# How to replace NaN with 0 in SQL

Tags: sql, database, nan, zero

I'm trying to take the average and median of several values but they are coming out incorrectly because the values I have in the table that are supposed to be 0 are listed as NaN in the database.

Is there a way I can replace all instances of NaN with 0 so that I can fix my average and median values?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: How did those `NaN` values end up there in the first place, as far as you know?

Comment: Is NaN coming from Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

`ISNUMERIC` is what you are looking for

```
Select case when ISNUMERIC(ColumnName)=1 then ColumnName else 0 end
```

This query will replace all `ColumnName` which is not a number

To calculate average. Try this query

```
Select 
AVG(Case When ISNUMERIC(ColumnName)=1 Then ColumnName Else 0 End) As [Average]
From Tablename
```